# Split a string in to columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, string, t-sql, split

I would like to split below string:

```
 @string = '?Reqid=325235&step=5&substep=13'
```

Desired output:

```
String                              Key   step substep 
?Reqid=325235&step=5&substep=13   325235   5     13
```

Edited:

So far I tried

```
declare @string varchar(100) = '?Reqid=325235&step=5&substep=13'

select @string String,

       substring(@string, len('?reqID=') + 1, (CHARINDEX('&step=', @string) - (len('?reqID=') + 1))) key,
       0 Step,
       0 SubStep
```

I didn't get a way to find for rest of columns

Current results:

```
String                              Key   step substep 
?Reqid=325235&step=5&substep=13   325235   0    0
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

SQL-Server is not well suited for this task, but there is a very nice work around using either JSON (version 2016+) or XML (starting form v2005):

```
DECLARE @string VARCHAR(100) = '?Reqid=325235&step=5&substep=13';
```

--The JSON approach (needs v2016+)

```
SELECT *
FROM OPENJSON(CONCAT('{"',REPLACE(REPLACE(STUFF(@string,1,1,''),'&','","'),'=','":"'),'"}'))
WITH(Reqid INT
    ,step INT
    ,substep INT);
```

--The XML approach (for older versions)

```
SELECT A.CastedToXml.value('(x/@Reqid)[1]','int') As Reqid
      ,A.CastedToXml.value('(x/@step)[1]','int') As step
      ,A.CastedToXml.value('(x/@substep)[1]','int') As substep
FROM (SELECT CAST('<x ' + REPLACE(REPLACE(STUFF(@string,1,1,''),'=','="'),'&','" ') + '" />'  AS XML)) A(CastedToXml);
```

The idea in short:

Using some simpe string operations we can transform your string in JSON

```
{"Reqid":"325235","step":"5","substep":"13"}
```

or XML

```
<x Reqid="325235" step="5" substep="13" />
```

Reading JSON is done with `OPENJSON` in connection with a `WITH`-clause (implicit pivoting). Reading XML's attributes is done using the XML's type method `.value()`.

Answer (score 1):

SQL Server *really* lacks regex functions, and this type of string manipulation would probably be better handled on application side.

That being said, assuming that the keys are always in the same sequence, you could do:

```
select 
    substring(
        @string, 
        charindex('Reqid=', @string) + len('Reqid='), 
        charindex('&', @string) 
            - charindex('Reqid=', @string) 
            - len('Reqid=')
    ) [key],
    substring(
        @string, 
        charindex('step=', @string) + len('step='), 
        charindex('&', @string, charindex('step=', @string) + len('step=')) 
            - charindex('step=', @string) 
            - len('step=')
    ) step,
    right(
        @string, 
        len(@string) - charindex('substep=', @string) - len('substep=') + 1
    ) substep
```

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=1896f0e3b478af9e8be6015a410ea0ae)**:

```
key    | step | substep
:----- | :--- | :------
325235 | 5    | 13
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming a fixed format for your string (URL) then the following pulls out the info requested:

```
declare @string varchar(100) = '?Reqid=325235&step=5&substep=13';

select
  substring(@string, End1+1, Start2-End1-1) ReqID
  , substring(@string, End2+1, Start3-End2-1) Step
  , substring(@string, End3+1, EndEnd-End3-1) SubStep
from (
  select @string String
    , charindex('?reqID=', @string) Start1
    , charindex('?reqID=', @string) + 6 End1
    , charindex('&step=', @string) Start2
    , charindex('&step=', @string) + 5 End2
    , charindex('&substep=', @string) Start3
    , charindex('&substep=', @string) + 8 End3
    , len(@string)+1 EndEnd
) X;
```

Result:

```
ReqID   Step    SubStep
325235  5       13
```

Answer (score 0):

This may help

```
select @string String,
substring(@string, len('?reqID=') + 1, (CHARINDEX('&step=', @string) - (len('?reqID=') + 1))) [Key],
SUBSTRING(@string, CHARINDEX('&step=', @string) + len('&step='), CHARINDEX('&substep', @string) - CHARINDEX('&step=', @string) - len('&step=')) Step,
SUBSTRING(@string, CHARINDEX('&substep=', @string) + len('&substep='), len(@string) - charindex('&substep=', @string)) Step
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using SQL Server 2016 or later, you can use `STRING_SPLIT` function to split the string by a character. See the full query below.

```
declare @string varchar(100) = '?Reqid=325235&step=5&substep=13', @c nchar(1) = N'='

SELECT @string AS [String], [1] AS [Key], [2] AS [step], [3] AS [substep]
FROM  
(
  SELECT TOP 100 PERCENT
  Val = substring(value, 0, charindex('&', value)), 
  R = ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( ORDER BY CHARINDEX(@c + value + @c, @c + @string + @c)  )
  FROM STRING_SPLIT(@string + '&', @c)  
  WHERE RTRIM(value)  '?Reqid'
  ORDER BY R
)
AS SourceTable  
PIVOT (  MAX(Val) FOR R IN ([1], [2], [3]) ) AS PivotTable;
```

[Demo on SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/9eecb/67064)

```
+---------------------------------+-----+--------+---------+
|             String              | Key |  step  | substep |
+---------------------------------+-----+--------+---------+
| ?Reqid=325235&step=5&substep=13 |  13 | 325235 |       5 |
+---------------------------------+-----+--------+---------+
```

**Update:** as `STRING_SPLIT` doesn't guarantee the order of results, I have used the `ROW_NUMBER()` function to make the order consistent. The character index of `=` is used for this purpose.

Comment: `STRING_SPLIT()` does not guarantee to return in the expected sort order...

Comment: @Shnugo you are right. I have changed my query to make the order consistent.

Comment: Well, this might work... But - as `STRING_SPLIT` needs v2016+, there is the much better JSON approach (see my answer).

Answer (score 0):

This is a pretty simple option that should be easy to understand:

```
DECLARE @string varchar(max) = '?Reqid=325235&step=5&substep=13';

DECLARE @RemainingString varchar(max) = SUBSTRING(@string, 8, LEN(@string));
DECLARE @AmpersandLocation int = CHARINDEX('&', @RemainingString);
DECLARE @Key varchar(100) = SUBSTRING(@RemainingString, 1, @AmpersandLocation - 1);
SET @RemainingString = SUBSTRING(@RemainingString, LEN(@Key) + 7, LEN(@RemainingString));
SET @AmpersandLocation = CHARINDEX('&', @RemainingString);
DECLARE @Step varchar(100) = SUBSTRING(@RemainingString, 1, @AmpersandLocation - 1);
DECLARE @Substep varchar(100) = SUBSTRING(@RemainingString, LEN(@Step) + 10, LEN(@RemainingString));

SELECT @string AS [String], @Key AS [Key], @Step AS [Step], @Substep AS Substep;
```